# Lose JRE 7 Security Alerts and Warnings

Tags: java, security, applet, certificate

I have a server with JRE 6 installed, i used to run an applet from the browser ok with no problems,

then i updated to JRE 7, now the applet gives 4 warning windows and in the console it shows warnings of missing lines in the manifest file, but after accepting all warnings it worked ok.

I wanted to lose the warnings, so i first tried to modify the manifest file thinking that will resolve it, but since modifying the manifest files, the manifest warnings in the console don't show but the 4 security prompts are still there.

normally i self sign the jar, after searching for a while i find it is something about the certificate, it must have a valid certificate.

i used a generated Keytool command from DIGICERT website to produce a certificate file and a jks file,

i tried to add the certificate through the java control panel and it asks for the keystore password, but whenever i enter the password that i used while creating the certificate, it gives wrong password.

After searching for sometime i read suggestion of adding the certificate to either windows certificates or the internet explorer certificates then export it, but when i try to add the certificate to any of them it says unrecognized file.

i imported the certificate to cacerts which i read is the java trusted key store, but still the applet produces 4 security prompts before running.

i removed one of the security prompts by hiding the mixed code warning from the java control panel.

but still there are 3 warnings.

i have been trying for sometime, so any suggestions or explanation so that i can understand better ?

Answer (score 1):

There have been recently security concerns on client-side java code execution.  Because of this, latest versions of JRE 7 tend to be extra-careful with everything they execute, specially self-signed applets and the likes of that.

Those security warnings will disappear when you provide an applet/web start/whatever client-side java executable code signed with a **valid** and **trusted by the client** certificate.

If you are in a corporate environment with an IT and/or security team, ask them for the right corporate certificate to sign your application with (it will probably be already trusted in the client workstations)

If you are deploying a java client-side component to be used widespread, you will need to sign it with a widely trusted certificate (here I cannot actually guide you... maybe you can get one off thawte?)

Comment: *"Those security warnings will disappear when you provide an applet/web start/whatever client-side java executable code signed with a **valid** and **trusted by the client** certificate."*  No certificate is 'trusted by the client' until/unless they tick 'always allow' when presented with code signed by a certificate issued by a Certification Authority.  Until that time, the warnings will be less severe, and fewer, but the user will still be prompted. +1 for the rest of the answer.